# Scala specs2 None is not equal to None

Tags: scala, unit-testing, equals, specs2, nonetype

I test that method output is as expected using `specs2` and `scala`. The test is as following:

```
call() must beEqualTo(expectedCall)
```

`expectedCall` is an instance of case class - same as `call()` returns. When i run tests i get following error

```
[error]      'CustomScriptParsedOutput(0,Some(List(IntegrationRecordMsg(-500.12,2016-03-10T18:20:00.000+01:00,Some(some note, CZ),Some(CZK),Some(List(WITHDRAWAL))))),None,None): models.CustomScriptParsedOutput'
[error]
[error]       is not equal to
[error]
[error]      'CustomScriptParsedOutput(0,Some(List(IntegrationRecordMsg(-500.12,2016-03-10T18:20:00.000+01:00,Some(some note, CZ),Some(CZK),Some(List(WITHDRAWAL))))),None,None): models.CustomScriptParsedOutput' (CustomTest.scala:53)
[error] Actual:   ...None)
[error] Expected: ...None)
```

where definition of case class is :

```
case class CustomScriptParsedOutput(
    code: Int, 
    records: Option[List[RecordMsg]] = None, 
    amount: Option[AmountMsg] = None, 
    error: Option[ErrorMsg] = None
)
```

**How come `None` is not equal to `None`?**

Comment: Are you sure that `None` is indeed what is not equal? Maybe that `-500.12` is a problem? Try `val res = call(); res must beEqualTo (res)`

Comment: It's using the `toString` output to attempt to show what isn't equal, but it can't find it. Perhaps share the type definitions for `RecordMsg`, `AmountMsg`, and `ErrorMsg`.

Comment: Tried to test each class attribute separately and it's indeed fault of only one attribute - specifically date one. The `toString` output confused me.

Comment: Yes I need to remove the message in that case. Sorry about that, I created an issue for this: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/463.

Comment: This issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to test each of the class attributes in a different line so you get sure of the problem. I find it hard the `None` comparsion to be the problem. Unless the 2 `None` are not options of the same type?